# please help me i can't connect to my google cloud shell since yesterday

Tags: google-cloud-shell

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMrH1.png) since yesterday, I cannot connect to the google cloud shell. Whenever I try to connect to the cloud shell, an error message comes up saying that "Google Cloud Shell is temporarily unavailable. Try connecting in a few minutes".

Comment: try to add &cloudshell=true at the end of the url and try again, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

What the url you trying to access ?

If '&cloudshell=true' is missing, try to add it at the end of the url and try again, let me know if it works.